# the load more ajax button in wordpress loads already displayed posts, instead of new ones

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display a list of "hot" products on the main page. by default, 4 products are displayed and 2 new products must be loaded using the "load more" button. when you click on the button, the first line is duplicated with the first two products instead of two new ones.
[link to the website](http://http://alex13746%20.beget.tech/)

front-page.php

```
 <div class="hot__items" id="ajax-container">



                        <?php
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'  => 'hot',
   'meta_value' => true
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
$max_pages = $products->max_num_pages;
if($products->have_posts()) : ?>

<?php 


            $pcount = count( $products->posts );
            while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post();
            $mainphoto = get_field("main_foto");
            $get_image_id = $mainphoto[id];
            $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($get_image_id, "full");
            $logo = get_field("logo_tovar");
            $get_logo_id = $logo[id];
            $logo_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($get_logo_id, "full");             
                        ?>
                      
                      
                       <div class="hot__item">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if( get_field("hot_comment") ): ?>
           <div class="hot_comment red-color"> <span></span> <?php the_field( "hot_comment" ); ?> </div>  
        <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="hot__imgs">
               <!--<img src="<?php echo $image_link;?>" alt="" class="hot__img">-->
               <!--<img src="<?php echo $logo_link;?>" alt="" class="hot__logo">-->
              <div class="item-fix-height fix-height_on-front">
                     <div class="scale_block_animate csomor-image-zoom" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_link;?>');"></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
          
            <div class="hot__text">
               <div class="hot__text_title">
               <p class="hot__name"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
               <?php if( get_field("model") ): ?>
               </div>
                  <div class="hot__text_about">
               <p class="hot__model"><b>Модель: </b><span class="red-color"><?php the_field( "model" ); ?></span></p>
               <?php endif; ?>
               <div class="hot__descr">
               <?php if( have_rows('harakteristiki_small') ):?>
                              
                              <div class="subsection__chtitle">Характеристики</div>
                                 <ul class="subsection__chlist">     
                                    
                                 <?php while( have_rows('harakteristiki_small')): the_row();?>
                                 <li class="subsection__chitem__on_front_page">
                                       <span class="subsection__chvar"><?php the_sub_field('har_title');?> </span>
                                       <span class="subsection__chval"><?php the_sub_field('har_value');?></span>
                                 </li>
                                 <?php endwhile;?>                            
                                    
                                 
                                 </ul>
                                 <?php endif; ?>
               
               </div>
               <div class="hot__bottom">
                  <!--<a href="#recall" data-topic="Горячее предложение(<?php the_title(); ?>)" class="popup-js hot__btn">Отправить запрос</a>-->
                  <ul class="hot__infos">
                     
                    
                    <!-- <?php if( get_field("nalichie") ): ?>
                     <li class="hot__info">
                        Наличие:
                        <span class="red-color"><?php the_field( "nalichie" ); ?></span>
                     </li>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php if( get_field("garantiya") ): ?>
                     <li class="hot__info">
                        Гарантия:
                        <span class="red-color"><?php the_field( "garantiya" ); ?></span>
                     </li>
                     <?php endif; ?> -->
                    <?php if( get_field("cena") ): ?>
                     <li class="hot__info hot__price">
                        Цена:
                        <span class="red-color hot-price"><?php the_field( "cena" ); ?></span>
                     </li>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                  </ul>

               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
         </div>
                      
                         <?php
                         
                        
                        endwhile;?>


                        <?php
        if($max_pages > 1){ ?>
                       <a id="load-more-products" href="#" class="good__btn" data-page="2">Смотреть еще</a>
                        <?php }?>


                        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;?>
                        </div>
```

functions.php

```
function get_hot_products() {
    global $post;

    
    $paged = $_POST['paged'] ? $_POST['paged'] : 1; 
    $return_html = ''; 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'  => 'hot',
        'meta_value'    => true
    );
    
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $max_pages = $products->max_num_pages; 
    if ($products->have_posts()):
         
        while ($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post();
    
            $mainphoto = get_field("main_foto");
            $get_image_id = $mainphoto[id];
            $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($get_image_id, "full");
            $logo = get_field("logo_tovar");
            $get_logo_id = $logo[id];
            $logo_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($get_logo_id, "full"); 
            $title = get_the_title();
            $permalink = get_the_permalink();
            $cena = get_field("cena");
           
            
            
            $return_html .= '<div class="hot__item"><a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . title . '">';
            
            if( get_field("hot_comment") ):
            $hot_comment = get_field( "hot_comment" );
            $return_html .= '<div class="hot_comment red-color"> <span></span>' . $hot_comment . '</div>  ';
            endif;
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__imgs"><div class="item-fix-height fix-height_on-front"><div class="scale_block_animate csomor-image-zoom" style="background-image: url(' . $image_link . ');"></div></div></div>';
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__text">';
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__text_title"><p class="hot__name">' . $title . '</p></div>';
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__text_about">';
            
            if( get_field("model") ):
            $model = get_field( "model" );
            $return_html .= '<p class="hot__model"><b>Модель: </b><span class="red-color">' . $model . '</span></p>';
            endif;
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__descr">';
            
            if( have_rows('harakteristiki_small') ):
            $return_html .='<div class="subsection__chtitle">Характеристики</div><ul class="subsection__chlist">';
                while( have_rows('harakteristiki_small')): the_row();
                    $har_title = get_sub_field( "har_title" );
                    $har_value = get_sub_field( "har_value" );
                    $return_html .='<li class="subsection__chitem__on_front_page"><span class="subsection__chvar">' . $har_title . '</span><span class="subsection__chval">' . $har_value . '</span></li>';
                endwhile;
            $return_html .='</ul>';
            endif;
            
            $return_html .='<div class="hot__bottom"><ul class="hot__infos"><li class="hot__info hot__price">Цена:<span class="red-color hot-price">' . $cena . '</span></li></ul></div>';
            
            $return_html .='</div>';
            
            $return_html .= '</div></div></a></div>';
            
            
        endwhile;
        
        
        
        

        
    endif;
    if ($paged < $max_pages)  { // if the current page is less than the total number of pages, then we display the button for loading
        $next_page = $paged + 1; // in the date attributes of the button, we pass the number of the next page and the id of the current terms
        $return_html .= '<a id="load-more-products" href="#" class="good__btn grey-bg" data-page="'. $next_page .'">Смотреть ещё</a>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $return_html; // returning the html code
    wp_die(); // "die"
}


add_action('wp_ajax_get_hot_products', 'get_hot_products'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_hot_products', 'get_hot_products');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `paged` value from the query string, but you're not passing it into the WP_Query args, so it's always grabbing the first ones.

```
    $paged = $_POST['paged'] ? $_POST['paged'] : 1; 
    $return_html = ''; 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
  --->  'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'  => 'hot',
        'meta_value'    => true
    );
```

Comment: thank you! it worked, but there is a small bug. when you click on "load more", the first time you click, loads the last two existing posts. after that, it already loads new ones

Comment: I think because if $paged is not set (then you are on the first page) you set the page to 1, so for the click on the load more you set the paged to 1 and load the first page again. Try to set it to 2 instead

Comment: this helped, but something is wrong in the formula for counting the remaining pages, since only two entries open, and there should be two more

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting the output of 4 products instead of 2. But this is not quite the right decision. At the moment it is suitable, since I have only 8 "hot products" on the site

```
 'posts_per_page' => 4,
```